# Github Actions steps id, how to call stdout of it?

Tags: github, github-actions

So I have issue because I want to store value of my branch prefix as id but I stumbled across... how to call it in other step?
I have something like this, so far I tried `steps.branch-prefix.output.stdout` and `steps,branch-prefix.output.branch-prefix` (first one was my instict because... what I do there returns all in stdout...)

Workflow sample:

```yaml
name: PR Semver
on: [push]

jobs:
  update-version:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Get current prefix
        id: branch-prefix
        run: echo $GITHUB_REF | sed -E 's/^refs\/heads\/(.*)\/.*/\1/'
      - name: Check if branch prefix is valid (major, minor, patch)
        run: |
          echo "Checking branch prefix..."
          echo "branch prefix: ${{ steps.branch-prefix.output.stdout }}"
          if [[ ${{ steps.branch-prefix.output.stdout }} != "major" && ${{ steps.branch-prefix.output.stdout }} != "minor" && ${{ steps.branch-prefix.output.stdout }} != "patch" ]]; then
            echo "Branch prefix is not valid, exiting..."
            exit 1
          fi
```

Comment: Yes! I mean it showed me the way of thinking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you need to use the `set-output` command

I think it would be something like

```
  - name: Get current prefix
    id: branch-prefix
    run: |
        prefix=$(echo $GITHUB_REF | sed -E 's/^refs\/heads\/(.*)\/.*/\1/')
        echo "::set-output name=prefix::$prefix"
```

And getting it with `${{ steps.branch-prefix.output.prefix }}`

Comment: Thanks! I did it in "one go" `run: echo "::set-output name=prefix::$(echo $GITHUB_REF | sed -E 's/^refs\/heads\/(.*)\/.*/\1/')"` as sugested above - but anyway thank you! I had no clue about that.

Comment: I had tried to do that but I struggled a bit with the quotation marks so I was too lazy to get this to be correct x). Glad it works, don't forget to mark the answer as a solution